# Google Play Console in Internal testing is unreviewed

Tags: android

Google Play Console in Internal testing is unreviewed when I already submit app content and Privacy policy. my app got status **Not reviewed**.

Comment: Please drop more information

Comment: I already get answer ! hehehe, because app content and Privacy policy not yet approved, so my app have status Not reviewed !